# how to make an unlockscreen function and refer to the previous page they open before they lock it if they succeed login in django

Tags: python, django

Im trying to make a lock_screen function where you can lock the website , if you want to go to toilet or not , and login again if you want to unlock it , and refer to the last page they visit before they lock it

The problem is , i put the name and the password right , but still redirect to lockscreen

here's the view.py

```
def unlockscreen(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            path = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
            guess = User.objects.get(username=username)
            identity = guess.id
            table2 = UserProfileInfo.objects.get(user_id=identity)
            role = table2.role
            user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)
            if user is not None:
                if role == 'Business Analyst':
                    request.session['username'] = username
                    request.session['role'] = role
                    login(request, user)
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
                else :
                    messages.error(request,"error1")
            else :
                messages.error(request,"error2")
        else :
            messages.error(request,"error3")
    form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request,"lock_screen.html",{"form":form})

#pretend the last page we visit is the index.html
@cache_control(no_cache=True, must_revalidate=True, no_store=True)
@login_required
def index_view(request):
    if request.session.get('username'):
        username = request.session['username']
        role = request.session['role']
        print(username)
        return render(request, 'index.html',{"username":username , "role":role})
    else :
        messages.error(request, "Login required")
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

def lockscreen(request):
    del request.session['username']
    return render(request, 'lock_screen.html')
```

lock_screen.html

```
<form method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="text" name="username"  value = {{request.user.username}} class ="form-control placeholder-no-fix" disabled="">
                <br>
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off" class="form-control placeholder-no-fix"> <br>

              </div>

              <br>
              {% if messages %}
              <ul class="messages">
                {% for message in messages %}
                <font color="red"><li {% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li></font>
                {% endfor %}
              </ul>
              {% endif %}
              <div class="modal-footer centered">
                <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-theme04" type="button">Cancel</button>
                <a href="{% url 'polls:unlockscreen' %}"><button class="btn btn-theme03" type="button">Login</button></a>
              </div>
              </form>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.login_view, name='login'),
    path('home/', views.index_view, name='indexing'),
    path('profile/', views.update_profile, name='profile'),
    path('chatroom/', views.chatroom, name='chat_room'),
    path('lockscreen/', views.lockscreen, name='lock_screen'),
    path('newsegment/', views.createsegment, name='newsegment'),
    path('definesegment/', views.list_all_table, name='definesegment'),
    path('load-data/', views.list_all_tabledependent, name='load-data'),
    path('load-column/', views.list_all_column, name='load-column'),
    path('manageuser/', views.manageuser, name='manageuser'),  
    path('approvallist/', views.approvallist, name='approvallist'),   
    path('approvalhistory/', views.approvalhistory, name='approvalhistory'),
    path('register/', views.register, name='register'),     
    path('logout/',views.logout,name='logout'),
    path('unlockscreen/',views.unlockscreen,name='unlockscreen')
    # path('polls/', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    # path('<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    # path('<int:pk>/results/', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    # path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

can someone help me check the error , and how to fix it .. thankyou for the help

P.S : i already search for  the problem ,it seems the unlockscreen method didnt get the request.method == 'POST' , but i already make the form method = "post" in html , whats wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understand correctly, You are able to lock the screen but when you are trying to unlock you are redirected to lockscreen.

If above is the case try below debugging:

1. Ensure when you are clicking on unlock/login button unlockscreen(request) is called/reached by adding print statement in the beginning of function. If unlockscreen is not reached means you have some problem in this line check url `<a href="{% url 'polls:unlockscreen' %}"><button class="btn btn-theme03" type="button">Login</button></a>`
2. Inside def unlockscreen(request) function there are multiple reasons when it will redirect to lockscreen like POST method, error1 ,error2 or error3.
3. print request.method and check if it is POST. Some times due to Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) POST methods received as OPTION.
4. check if error1 ,error2 or error3 is not occurred.

Comment: The method i get is GET , but how it possible .. i already put the <form method="post"> there

Comment: Make sure you don't have multiple lock_screen.html file in your project, and indent code properly and check if all tags are closed propely